# Collapsing Toolbar with image from url?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, material-design, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I did a collapsing toolbar with image for my android app. It works perfectly with the image from drawable. My problem is when I retrieve image from a URL and assign it to the same image view. The collapsing toolbar is not working. Titles gone, Can't scroll, and no image.

Here is my screenshots.

[image: Image from drawable]        [image: After set image from async task]

Picture 1 is image from drawable and 
Picture 2 is image retrieved from URL

**Activity:**

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.graphics.Palette;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;


    public class RecipeDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
        ImageView image;
        ImageView img;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_display);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            //default header image for toolbar
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.header);

            //Loading image using async task
            new LoadImage().execute("http://www.twinaccommodation.com/media/313799/pub_food_281x281.jpg");

            collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Collapsing");
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

       }

       //async task
       private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();
               pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RecipeDisplay.this);
               pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
               pDialog.show();

            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(args[0]).getContent());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img) {

                if (img != null) {
                    image.setImageBitmap(img);
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                } else {

                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RecipeDisplay.this, "Error retrieving image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

No error is thrown in LOGCAT too... Please Help me on this.

***EDIT : XML Layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:src="@drawable/pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum..."
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    style="@style/fab"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

Comment: is this on the emulator or real device and have you verified internet connection, and have you added internet permission to the manifest ?

Comment: Post your layout file code.

Comment: yes i added the permisison in the manifest. So not a permission problem. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Edit. layout file added

Comment: I have the same exact issue even when I'm using Picasso. Were you able to resolve this? If yes then how?

Answer (score 13):

With android studio 1.5 and above, you can create a scrolling template.
Then add the imageview to the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.codephillip.app.MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/placeholder_image"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_stretch_detail"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then use picasso to load it into image

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ImageView toolbarImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_id);

        String url = "" //place your url here
        picassoLoader(this, toolbarImage, url);
     }

        public void picassoLoader(Context context, ImageView imageView, String url){
        Log.d("PICASSO", "loading image");
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                        //.resize(30,30)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                .error(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

add the picasso library to your gradle dependencies as well

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem with yours is that, while you give no drawable to your image view then the view loads up with initial height of 0dp, because you have given `wrap_content` in height param. Now even after the image gets loaded in image view, since the view hasn't been invalidated so it still has 0dp height. So you don't see the image.

solutions u can try:

1) Give your image view an initial `height` of say `200dp` and it will work like a charm.

2) If you want to use height as wrap_content then you might as well invalidate the view ( meaning draw it again on the screen with new params),  try this: `imageView.invalidate();`.
Type this here in this block:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap img) {

            if (img != null) {
                image.setImageBitmap(img);
                pDialog.dismiss();
                image.invalidate();

            } else {

                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(RecipeDisplay.this, "Error retrieving image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
```

Comment: preferably you can use image loading libraries. Piccasso would be great for your case.

Comment: Giving ImageView a specific height solved the issue. I fixed it to "@dimen/app_bar_height".

Answer (score 1):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library and use this to get bitmap from `AsyncTask`

```
Bitmap image = Picasso.with(getAppilicationContext()).load(YourString).get();
```

then in `onPostExecute` set image to `collapsingToolbar`

Or use this AsyncTask

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

And start task with:

```
new DownloadImageTask(YourImageView)
     .execute(YourURLString);
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks mate

Comment: Same problem like my async task. no image is being shown

Comment: Check INTERNET permission... the code works perfectly @sughan90

Comment: Hi guys, i seem to have a similar problem, it doesnt load. Since i have used this downloading task plenty of times, it doesnt seem to work using Collapsible Toolbar. Since if i comment out: `<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout` it works fine, image loads perfectly. Can someone elaborate on this?